# Redirect URL for OAuth2 with Google Drive, in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, xamarin.auth

I want to access to google drive from my Xamarin-android app. I have created in google developer console my app as "other type" and used the following code to access google drive:

```
   this.auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(Constants.GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID,
        Constants.GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET, Constants.GOOGLE_DRIVE_SCOPE,
        Constants.GOOGLE_AUTH_URL, Constants.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL, 
        Constants.GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL);
   auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
      if(eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) {
          account = eventArgs.Account;
      }
   };
```

Where the constants are defined as follows:

```
public static Uri GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth");
public static Uri GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL = new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto");
public static Uri GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = new Uri("https://googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/auth");
public static string GOOGLE_DRIVE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
```

(For obvious reasons, I am not showing the client ID neither the client secret but they are strings rightly initialized)

The problem is that when the auth is completed, the "isauthenticated" is always false independently if I rightly login or not.
I think it is something to do with the retrieve of the token. But I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: I am using Xamarin.Auth

Comment: According to the Drive API for Android [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api), the only supported scopes are drive.file and drive.appfolder. See if that helps solve your problem.